# Linux Programmatically find UUID's of Partitions

Tags: c, linux, uuid

So I'm working on a fairly stripped down custom linux build at my job.  I'm trying to discover a way to get the UUID's of the harddrive and zram partitions using C.

`libblkid` isn't available, `/etc/blkid.tab` doesn't exist, `/etc/fstab` only provides the filesystem name and type.  `/etc/mtab` is empty.  `udev` isn't available either. `/dev/disk/...` doesn't exist.

`/proc/partitions` is available but even on normal linux systems doesn't provide a UUID.

`fdisk` provides only information on the actual disk, no UUID, and nothing about the flash.

I've looked at the source for `blkid` and it seems to be reading `/etc/blkid.tab` unless another file has been provided as it's source of information through an environment variable.  I'm trying to find out if there is some other way that I might be able to open the drives and find the UUID or if linux stores them in some other way that I'm unaware of.

Comment: I believe that `blkid` uses `/etc/blkid.tab` as a cache, and that it will probe the hardware on a cache miss.

Comment: The UUIDs are stored in the superblocks of the respective filesystems, you need the logic in `libblkid` for the filesytems you have (prob. ext2/3/4 for hdd, and/or zram and fat32 for the flash mem. ?) What exactly hinders you from building a stripped down version of `libblkid` with only the FSs you have insteda of rolling your own? The hope that it might be simpler? If you have ext-fs only you might have some luck with `dumpe2fs -h $DEV`

Comment: I could probably build a stripped down version, I was just hoping there was something else available since it doesn't seem to exist on the linux build as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you aware that there are UUIDs for both partitions and for filesystems?  Neither is always present.  Linux itself does not know about UUIDs, the entire concept is handled in user-space by programs installed on your system, and these programs all use libblkid, as far as I know.

You say that you want partition UUIDs, but you probably actually want filesystem UUIDs.

### Libblkid

Sorry, but when you say that "libblkid isn't available", what does that even mean?  I am a bit skeptical.  Libblkid is open source and free software, after all, so if you don't have a copy of libblkid it is trivial to get one.  Libblkid is also written in C, and you're already writing code in C, so you *must* have a C compiler around to compile libblkid.  You can make a static version of it if necessary.

The main way libblkid works is by reading data directly from block devices.  For disks, this means reading the partition table.  For filesystems, this means reading from the filesystem superblock.  Theoretically, if you can't use libblkid (which is highly unusual, even for stripped-down systems) you can parse the partition table or superblock yourself.

Libblkid does use a cache file at `/etc/blkid.tab` but this is just a cache and it is not necessary.

Other interfaces to UUIDs, like `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, are created in user-space by programs which use libblkid.

### Filesystem UUIDs

Normally, if you are talking about the UUIDs you see in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, which are the same UUIDs you use in `/etc/fstab`, you are talking about the filesystem UUID.  The libblkid library does the hard work of decoding the superblocks for a wide array of filesystems.  You can see, for example, the UUID for Ext2 filesystems appear in [libblkid src/superblocks/ext.c line 48](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libblkid/src/superblocks/ext.c#L48).  Libblkid supports many filesystem types and you can see them in the `src/superblocks` directory.

Not all filesystem types have UUIDs.  Ext2 has a UUID, FAT32 does not, but it has a different ID which serves the same purpose.

### Partition UUIDs

If you really need the unique partition UUID, you can also get that.  Libblkid reads this out of the partition table.  Only certain types of partition tables have UUIDs for partitions at all.  GPT does, but DOS partition tables do not.

Comment: I just meant that libblkid isn't currently built into the linux build and that I was hoping to work without it.

Comment: @incanus86: You don't need to add it to the build, you can use static linking if you want.  However much work it is to use libblkid, it is probably 50x as much work to not use it.

Answer (score 1):

UUID is not a partition setting, it is stored at filesystem level.

> `# tune2fs -l /dev/sda4|grep UUID
>    Filesystem UUID:          7a7be8cb-8271-4442-b0c3-2c1df2eaab6c`

Comment: There are partition UUIDs also.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the symbolic links in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.  There are POSIX system calls like `opendir` and `readlink` that you can use.  You can also run `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`, which outputs something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 27 11:23 ec13636b-a731-41d0-8273-442f194cf37f -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 27 11:23 ed8799bc-34c3-4d37-b1b2-44562423a298 -> ../../sda1
```

Comment: Oh, I just saw that `/dev/disk` doesn't exist for you.  I still want to keep my answer here because it's the right answer for most people.  Maybe you could find the code that generates that directory; I'm not sure if it's part of udev or if it's in the kernel.  If it's in the kernel, you could enable it.  If it's in udev, you should be able to learn from it and do the same thing in your C code.

Comment: While this works most of the time, I'd hesitate to call it the right answer.  This does little more than introduce extra layers of indirection between you and libblkid, which udev uses to create the entries in /dev.  It's even quite possible to run Linux without udev, in which case this answer wouldn't work at all, but libblkid would keep working.

Comment: OK, I didn't know how those symbolic links are implemented.  So yeah, libblkid sounds good.